# Minecraft 1.19.2 Bug or a Misunderstanding of Command Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or not, so let me give somer background.  Running in Vanilla 1.19.2, so no mods or anything.  Not even a texture pack.

It's my understanding a command block needs a redstone signal to activate.  However, it's also my understanding that a block can act as the 'activated' signal when next to a command block to start the impulse block.

However, it seems that in this 'indirect' method, it doesn't work with chains.

This may describe what I mean better:

[image]

A is the indirect chain, while B is the direct chain.  The yellow wool in front of A1 will have a button on it, and B1 has a button directly on it.

A1 is configured to `say Starting indirect chain.`.  B1 is configured to `say Starting direct chain.`  Both A2 and B2 simply run `say Chain 1 reached.`

When I click the button directly on B1, it executes the entire chain as expected.

[image]

However, when I click the button on the block in front of A1, it should activate A1 and then A2 afterwards.  However, it only executes A1.  As seen below, it only executes the first block and nothing happens with the chain block behind it.

[image]

What baffles me is that, effectively, A1 *has* a redstone signal so it's my understanding this should chain to A2 and execute where it says the chain block command.

Am I misunderstanding how command blocks work, or is this a bug in 1.19.2?

Comment: What modes are the command blocks set to? A1 and B1 should be on "Redstone" and B2 and A2 should be on "Always activated". You might be missinterpreting as B2 gets indirectly activated, but A2 doesnt. If you had B3, I dont think it would get activated (If it was on redstone mode)

Comment: All are set to redstone mode.  Maybe that's what I'm doing.  I assume then that A2 and B2 then in this example should be set to conditional then like I have them so they don't trigger randomly when we don't want them to?

Comment: @BunnyMerz that was the problem, can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Conditional will only activate the command if the previous one was succesful, not if the precious one was activated, careful with that! You should only set the first two (A1 and B1) to 'require redstone' and all others as 'always active'

Comment: @BunnyMerz this simple case i have here is simple.  In the real chain of what i'm working with, there's `execute if ...` conditional handlers on the impulse block so as long as conditional on the subsequent blocks will only execute if the impulse block is successfully triggered all will be good :)

Comment: @BunnyMerz Followup to my last message: I just left them as unconditional but the chain blocks use `execute if` syntax as well so that 'conditional' isn't confusing and the condition is directly in the block.  Makes that a little simpler when looking at the chain what to do when each section hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When command blocks are set to "require redstone", they will only be able to be activated when powered by redstone. Being powered by redstone does not always mean 'run the command'!

In the case of chain (aqua-marine) command blocks, they will only allow or not commands to be ran, and the commands will be ran if another command block facinig it gets activated. For the orange and purple (repeat and impulse) they will run the command if powered by redstone.

In OP's sitatuion, A1, A2, B1 and B2 are set to "Require redstone", but B2 is being indirectly powered and A2 isn't, which causes the weird behaviour of A1 "not powering" A2. If there was an B3 (chain and require redstone), it wouldn't be powered just like A2.